# When I get dublicate key error for email (unique) , I want to check another field in mongodb findoneandupdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb with nodejs . I want to update user , if dublicate key error happens for email (unique) then check isdelete(not unique) field .If isdelete equals to true , update user otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //user is a model

User.findOne({ 'email': req.body.email, 'isDeleted': true}, function (err, result) {

  if(result) { //if user isdeleted true then update user

   //write here your update code

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Kuldeep Mishra I will explain it clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userFindByid }, {
    $set: {
      "email": req.body.email,
      "username": req.body.username,
      "phone_number": req.body.phone_number,
      "address": req.body.address,
      "isBenefactor": req.body.isBenefactor,
      "location": req.body.location
    }
  }, { runValidators: true, context: 'query' }, (err, doc) => {

    if (err) {
// if request email has already exist in db I want to check that emails isDeleted field in here . if isDeleted is true I want to update .
      return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    else {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Your account was updated' });
    }
  })
//


Let me explain  scenario clearly,
 I registered with an email address(first@gmail.com) then I deleted my account =>(first@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=true 
After that I again registered with another email address(second@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=false
Now I want to update my second email address with first one I will get an unique key error because (first@gmail.com) is in mydb ,but I have to da update process because  (first@gmail.com)=>IsDelete=true 
If I use { 'email': req.body.email, 'isDeleted': true} I can not update (second@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=false

I can fix the problem by using too much if statements , but I dont want to use if statements too much. I am looking for best practice for that problem.

I hope I could explain
```